# Print pos receipt with css

Tags: css, xml, odoo, odoo-15

i am currently using odoo 15 point of sale, In that i want to change the receipt style to boxed layout. I already inhereated the OrderReceipt.xml and updated the receipt as per my need and also i have made the print in A4 format, but "i want the total part background-color to black and the color of text to white" i have provided inline css on the xml but in the receipt screen in receipt i can see its getting reflected but when i print that pdf that pdf is not reflecting the colors, need help to print it with color and background color any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<templates id="template" xml:space="preserve">
    <t t-inherit="point_of_sale.OrderReceipt" t-inherit-mode="extension" owl="1">
        <div class="pos-receipt" position="attributes">
            <attribute name="class">pos-receipt bg-dark text-white</attribute>
        </div>
    </t>
</templates>
```